# Add spacing between bootstrap cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add some pacing between cards that are provided and I was having some trouble adding some space between the cards.

This is how it currently looks like in my on my site:
[image]

Currently my code looks like this

```
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
```

I was wondering if i have to add some sort of padding like ml-5 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.card{
  margin-right:20px!important;
  }
your can modify your card default margin and definitely used !important
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add following class according to your requirement in parent div. Where you have "row justify-content-center" classes.

```
    Where property is one of: 
   
    m - for classes that set margin
    p - for classes that set padding

    Where sides is one of:
    
    t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
    b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
    l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
    r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
    x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
    y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
    blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `margin` to each child `div` just like below use **full page view** to see this snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="row justify-content-center p-4">
            <div class="card mr-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mr-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mr-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

margin horizontaly

```
<div class="card mx-3" style="width: 18rem;">
```

margin left

```
<div class="card ml-3" style="width: 18rem;">
```

margin right

```
<div class="card mr-3" style="width: 18rem;">
```